# Can I mine with an Intel Celeron R 1820?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mining-hardware

I just started getting the into Monero and it took for about 14 days to sync (it still has some remaining blocks and I use the GUI wallet created by community), though my question is this, can I even mine any?

The system as I mentioned before is an Intel Celeron 1820 (2.7 GHz) with NVIDIA GeForce 8500 GT.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but don't expect to mine a block any time soon with such a low powered CPU.

Comment: Would joining "Pool mines" help thou'?

Comment: The amount you'd earn is directly related to your hashrate, which is directly related to how good your CPU and memory is.  You will undoubtedly spend more on electricity that you will earn with that CPU. Pools don't earn you more, just allow smaller more frequent payouts.

Comment: Tnx for your guidances